# Replace repeating characters with only one character in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if a string contains more than or equals 3 times a letter/number and replace it with only one letter/number. For example:

```
IIIII havvvvve a bigggg tesssssttttt tomorrow soooo iiii 2222551111 haveeee to do this rightttttt
```

To became like this

```
I have a big test tomorrow so i 2551 have to do this right.
```

How can this be done with `preg_replace` ?

Comment: "Tomorrow" would become "tomorow" unless you have a dictionary lookup.

Comment: @Ozzy There are no words in the English language with the same letter more than twice in a row, so it's safe to assume the repetition of 3+ the same letter. Although the repetition in his question appears to be abit random, so the problem would still persist on a string like "II havvee a bbig tesst" etc...

Answer (score 3):

**Regex:**

```
([A-Za-z0-9])\1\1+
```

This would match more than or equals 3 times a letter/number and captures the first letter or Number. Finally the whole string was replaced with the character in the group index 1.

**Replacement string:**

```
\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/26)

```
<?php
$text = 'IIIII havvvvve a bigggg tesssssttttt tomorrow soooo iiii 2222551111 haveeee to do this rightttttt';
$pattern = '~([A-Za-z0-9])\1\1+~';
echo preg_replace($pattern,'\1',$text);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
I have a big test tomorrow so i 2551 have to do this right
```

Comment: `.` matches more than just letters and numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Za-z0-9])(\1{2,})?
```

Try this.Replace with $1.

See demo..

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/27

Comment: `\w` includes `_` symbol also.

Comment: it's not a good idea to capture all the words which don't have any repeated characters.